# How to get the selected nodes in p:tree when they're pre-selected from ManagedBean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my application I am using the p:tree in selectionMode:checkbox. Code is below:

```
<p:tree id="tree_permissoes" value="#{mBTipoUsuario.root}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{mBTipoUsuario.selectedNodes} widgetVar="treeSingleWidget""> 
  <p:treeNode>
         <h:outputText value="#{node}"/> 
  </p:treeNode>
```

I am having some problems to get the selected nodes in "mBTipoUsuario.selectedNodes" array. When the user click in a certain button I load the p:tree with some pre-selected nodes from the managed bean. Then, the user can select some other nodes, of their choice, in the p:tree and submit back to the managed bean. The problem is, in "mBTipoUsuario.selectedNodes" array, I just get the nodes that the user explicitly checked, but a miss the nodes that were pre-selected from the managed bean.

**THE QUESTION IS: How to get both, the pre-selected nodes from the managed bean and those nodes explicitly selected by the user?**

I have already tried to select the nodes I want to be pre-selected in the client side, as shown here: [PrimeFaces Tree component, setting selected node from managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597134/primefaces-tree-component-setting-selected-node-from-managed-bean)

But I have not any success. Can anyone help-me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem. Here is the solution for future readers. It is possible to check the Nodes from the client-side. This way is possible to recover all the nodes properly in the managed beans, even the the nodes pre-selected by the application, since we check them from Client-Side.

The solution for doing it is shown here: [PrimeFaces Tree component, setting selected node from managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597134/primefaces-tree-component-setting-selected-node-from-managed-bean)

But in our case, we don't want to select the nodes, we want to check them, so we can use the function 'toggleCheckboxNode' istead.

The final code is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append("PrimeFaces.widgets.treeSingleWidget.toggleCheckboxNode(");
                        sb.append("$(\"#frm_edit\\\\:tree_permissoes\\\\:");
                        sb.append(root.getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(k).getRowKey());
                        sb.append("\")");
                        sb.append(", true)");
                        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(sb.toString());
```